# How to plugin anchor tag with jquery

Tags: php

I have an existing anchor tag - how do I add a call to a JavaScript function to it, which will run when clicked? I have created pagination dynamically, and would like to call a JavaScript function in the href of the anchor, to both run the function and go to a new page.

Below is an example of the page I would like to display.
[image]

This is my html code:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination" id="pagination">
        <?php for ($b=1; $b <= $a ; $b++) {?>
          <li>
          <a class="anchorClass" id="anch" href="<?php echo base_url('attandance/staff_time_depart/'.$depart.'/'.$date_from.'/'.$date_to.'/'.$b) ?>"> <?php echo $b ?> </a>
          </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var b = '<?php echo $b; ?>';
        var a_href = $("#anch").attr("href");
        $(function () {
            window.pagObj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: b,
                visiblePages: 5,
                href: 'true',
                // anchorClass: a_herf,
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                    console.info(page + ' (from options)');
                }
            }).on('page', function (event, page) {
                console.info(page + ' (from event listening)');
            });
        });
    </script>
```